ggplot geom_raster produces blank space for some values
I have a dataframe like this
  Hoehe   75   65   50   35   20   5
1  51.5  9.5 10.5 10.0  8.1  9.8 8.8
2  41.5 10.9 11.1 10.9  9.7 11.1 9.9
3  31.5 10.7 11.0 11.3 10.6 10.2 9.5
4  21.5  9.7 10.1 10.2 11.1  9.8 9.0
5  11.5  9.2  9.6  9.2 10.9  8.9 8.8
6   1.5  7.7  8.0  8.6 10.6  7.3 7.2

that I would like to plot in a 2D interpolated plot.
I reshaped the data and did a plot with geom_raster.
library (ggplot2)

data_reshape <- data %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = `75`:`5`, 
    names_to = "Entfernung",
    values_to = "value"
  )

data_reshape$Entfernung = as.numeric(data_reshape$Entfernung)

ggplot(data_reshape, aes(Entfernung, Hoehe)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = value), interpolate = TRUE) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 58)) + #set lower and upper limits of your y-axis
  scale_fill_gradient(low= "yellow", high ="red")

However in the final plot it looks as if there is a data gap at 40 cm.

Any ideas why this problem appears and how to solve it?

The issue is that geom_raster is meant for evenly spaced grids, where the width used to draw the tiles is set according to the minimum width between grid points which is 10 in your case. However, as your grid points are not evenly spaced you end up with some gaps between points which are further apart than the minimum width.
One option to fix that would be to fill up your grid to make it evenly spaced for which I use tidy::complete and interpolation via zoo::na.approx.
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

data_reshape <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = `75`:`5`,
    names_to = "Entfernung",
    values_to = "value"
  )

data_reshape$Entfernung <- as.numeric(data_reshape$Entfernung)

data_reshape <- data_reshape |>
  complete(Hoehe, Entfernung = full_seq(Entfernung, 5)) |>
  mutate(
    value = zoo::na.approx(value), .by = Hoehe
  )

ggplot(data_reshape, aes(Entfernung, Hoehe)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = value), interpolate = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red")


DATA
data <- structure(list(
  Hoehe = c(51.5, 41.5, 31.5, 21.5, 11.5, 1.5),
  `75` = c(9.5, 10.9, 10.7, 9.7, 9.2, 7.7), `65` = c(
    10.5,
    11.1, 11, 10.1, 9.6, 8
  ), `50` = c(
    10, 10.9, 11.3, 10.2, 9.2,
    8.6
  ), `35` = c(8.1, 9.7, 10.6, 11.1, 10.9, 10.6), `20` = c(
    9.8,
    11.1, 10.2, 9.8, 8.9, 7.3
  ), `5` = c(
    8.8, 9.9, 9.5, 9, 8.8,
    7.2
  )
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  "1", "2", "3",
  "4", "5", "6"
))

